# RabbitMQ SSL issue - what should the path to the certificates be?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, openssl, rabbitmq, acl

I'm setting up RabbitMQ on Ubuntu which works fine. But I'm trying to set up SSL but I suspect RabbitMQ can't find the path I've put to the certificates. I'm following the tutorial here using OpenSSL https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

The certificates were set up in a folder /rmqca - when I set this up as I was logged in as chrisadmin (I think I have root permissions but I'm a little hazy on what that means/if it's correct). So I just did mkdir /rmqca.

I believe rabbitmq executes as a user rabbitmq - how do I make it so it can see this path from it's config?

Comment: did you set the permission for `rabbitmq` group ?

Comment: Could you talk me through how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner using:

```
sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /rmqca
```

And read also this:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html